# CDF of the length of a projection of a random unit vector in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, random-variables

Q1: Let $\vec{u}$ be a random unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Denote by $U$ the length of the projection of $\vec{u}$ on the $x,y$ plane. Find $F_U,f_U,\mathbb E[U].$ (CDF, PDF, EV)

Q2: Let $\vec{u}$ be a random unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Denote by $U$ the length of the projection of $\vec{u}$ on the $x$-axis. Find $F_L,f_L,\mathbb E[L].$

I want to solve Q1 with somewhat similar solution to Q2, but i'm having troubles with finding the angles, the length of $U$ and the correct integrals. Here's my Solution to Q2:

Let $\vec{u}$ be a random unit vector in $\mathbb R^2$, by polar coordinates $\vec{u}=(r,\theta)$, where $r=1$ and $\theta \sim U([0,2\pi])$ .
$L$ is the projection's length of $\vec{u}$ on the x-axis:
[image]

now, clearly the projection can fall either on the negative or the positive side of the x-axis, with same length for 3 more vectors created by rotating $\vec{u}$ by $\frac{\pi}{2},\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2}$, so $L=|cos\theta|$.

$F_L(t)=0$ for $t\le0$ and $F_L(t)=1$ for $t\ge 1$.

for $0<t<1$ we get:
\begin{align*} 
F_L(t) &= P(-t\leq \cos\theta\leq t) \\ 
&= P \biggl( \bigl( \pi -\arccos(t) \leq \theta \leq \arccos(t) \bigr) 
\cup \bigl( \tfrac{3\pi}{2} - \arccos(t) \leq \theta \leq 2\pi 
 \arccos(t) \bigr) \biggr) \\
&= F_\theta(\arccos(t)) - F_\theta(\pi - \arccos(t)) 
+ F_\theta(2\pi-\arccos(t)) - F_\theta(\tfrac{3\pi}{2}-\arccos(t)) \\
&= 1 - \frac{2\arccos(t)}{\pi} 
\end{align*}

from here it's pretty straight forward to find $f_L,\mathbb E[L]$.

Please help me find $F_U$ for Q1, with somewhat similar tactics. please try to keep it simple as possible, since i'm only a first degree CS undergraduate, with narrow toolbox (related courses i've taken are calculus 1 and 2, and introduction to probability).

This is **not** a duplicate of [this quesion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3564432/expected-length-of-unit-vector-projection-in-mathbbr3), because my question should be solved with very basic tools.
Thanks